# How can I load a predefined rule set to a sonar profile

Tags: java, sonarqube

i have a local sonar server running. i would like to create a new profile with a set of rules that were predefined by someone else. i have the XML file containing all the rules.

is there a way to upload the XML file to the profile and not define the rules manually?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you are logged into Sonar.

Click on Quality Profiles in the top navigation bar, then click on "Restore Profile" on the right hand side under the search bar. Make sure you have all the applicable quality plugins that the export is using or the restore will choke.

Comment: What are the required plugins for restoring profile? I replicating some profile from one Sonar to another, but its not importing rules.

Comment: what are the plugin you are mentioning

Comment: Things like CheckStyle, PDM, FindBugs etc.
See the [Plugin Library](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Library).

Answer (score 0):

May be a bit old thread but worth answering this question with exact steps as I struggled alot with this problem.

Though its a hacky way to import rulebook from prod to your local. But it works and can save valuable time.

Here are the steps:

- Login to SonarQube as admin.
- Create a new Quality Profile as below:
  [image]
- Download the default xml from local sonarqube by clicking on `Backup` button. Lets call this file `local-rulebook.xml`
  [image]
- Open both the `prod-rulebook.xml` file & `local-rulebook.xml` in notepad.
- Delete the selected part from `local-rulebook.xml` & replace with the content from `prod-rulebook.xml`. Save the file.
  P.S: Do not change the value of `<profile><name>{yourProfileName}</name>`.
  [image]
- Go back to sonarQube and Click `Restore` at top-right corner of the screen.
  [image]
- Import the newly updated file
  [image]
- Change the default profile type.
  [image]

Congrats you successfully imported the `prod-rulebook.xml` to your `local` sonarqube.